# how to capture the mouseover element?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

i am developing an autocomplete feature.but i am facing one problem there...

when i click on the suggestion box one of the results will not enter into the suggest html box...

```
function handleOnMouseOver(oTr)
{
    deselectAll();
    oTr.className ="highlightrow";
    position = oTr.id.substring(2, oTr.id.length);
    updateKeywordValue(position);
}
```

can you plz tell the solution

thanks

function updateKeywordValue(oTr)
{

var oKeyword = document.getElementById("keyword");

var strKeyword="";

var crtLink = document.getElementById("a" +oTr.id.substring(2,oTr.id.length)).toString();

crtLink = crtLink.replace("-", "_");

crtLink = crtLink.substring(0, crtLink.length);

oKeyword.value=unescape(crtLink.substring(googleurl.length, crtLink.length));

strKeyword=oKeyword.value.toString();

if (oTr.id.substring(2,oTr.id.length)==0)
{

oKeyword.value=strKeyword.substring(3,strKeyword.length);

}

selectedKeyword=oKeyword.value;

}

Answer (score 1):

you should get rid of the second parameter in the `substring()` method. Since you just want the remainder of the string, I'm guessing, that is the default if you don't set a second value.

```
position = oTr.id.substring(2);
```

My guess is that you are getting the value of the keyword from the id, and pushing that into the input box, right?  If that's the case, we'll need to see more of your code. Specifically, I'd like to see the `updateKeywordValue` function and I'd also like to know if the text that they are hovering over is the text you are trying to send the input box. If so, you could probably simplify the whole thing and go with something like:

```
function handleOnMouseOver(oTr)
{
    deselectAll();
    oTr.className ="highlightrow";
    keywordbox.value = oTr.innerHTML;
```

}

But this is based on the assumption that the only data inside the hovered row is the text, and no other html. And I had to make up a name for your input box.

But if this way off, this is because we need more information to see the real problem.